# Get id from clicked paragraph in download template in Blueimps Jquery fileupload

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm trying to customize Blueimp Jquery File Upload, so it returns the uploaded pdf in an `<object>` tag, which actually works great.
Now I'm trying to make a button to toggle the `<object>` pdf on/off, but when I'm triggering the event, I can't traverse or even do something as simple as getting the ID from the button pressed.

Here is the download-template to Jquery File Upload I'm using:

```html
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
        {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-download fade">
            <td>
                <span class="preview">
                    {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                    {% } %}
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="name">
                    {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                    {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                    {% } %}
                </p>


<!--What I'm trying to press to toggle the pdfviewer -->
                <p style="line-height: 30px;
margin: auto;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
background: #555;
border: solid 1px #666;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 3px;
user-select: none; cursor:pointer;" id="hejsaa" onclick="Sayhi()">
                    Tryk her for at vise eller skjule elementer
                </p>
                <object class="pdfviewer" width="400" height="500" type="application/pdf" id="noget" data="{%=file.url%}?#zoom=85&scrollbar=1&toolbar=0&navpanes=0"></object>

                {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
                {% } %}
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}" {% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}' {% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
                {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
                {% } %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% } %}
    </script>
```

And here is the script getting triggered (and it does get triggered successfully):

```js
function Sayhi() {
console.log($(this).attr('id'));
$(this).next().toggle(1000);
}
```

My console log says undefined when I press the `<p>` tag.

I've also tried traversing through the elements, but I've been unsuccessful there as well.

Edit: It seems to have something to do with the fact that BlueImp Jquery File Upload adds the HTML to the DOM dynamically, which means no handlers are attached and it wont register the click event/bind it to the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the element by parameter and get it on the function.

See the example:

```js
function Sayhi(e) {
 console.log($(e).attr('id'));
 $(e).next().toggle(1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="hejsaa" onClick="Sayhi(this)"> Tryk her for at vise eller skjule elementer </p>
<p style="display:none;">Next</p>
```